# QGIS load WFS Layer into WMS based Map shows wrong position

Tags: wms, wfs, epsg, output

I experienced the problem, that I tried to load a WFS onto a WMS based Map. I double checked the CRS  which is EPSG:25832 for either the Map and the WFS Information within the source and my project. Still the data is projected in a completely different location.

I add pictures.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image: this is what the debugging shows me, when I add WFS that gives wrong position]

Comment: what does the data coming back from the WFS look like?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Where in Europe should the WFS data be displayed on the map

Comment: Can you use the debugging tools to find and report the actual HTTP requests made by QGIS to the WMS and the WFS server

Comment: thanks for your answers! 
I am working on a project where p.e. the active windcraft would be displayed on a map for the region of Baden-Würrtemberg in Germany. As I am not this far into qgis I dont know the debugging tool nor the communication between the Server and my Qgis. I will start searching for this...

Comment: So I found out about the debugging tool and kept recording while asking for connection between my project and the server. Picture can be found inside the first post :)

Comment: Picture doesn't give the information requested was asking for the URLs used to fetch the backdrop raster map (WMS) and vector data (WFS)

Comment: You need to use View > Panels > Debugging/Development tools to find a GetMap and a GetFeature request.

Comment: Okay, I added a log from the debugging tool. 
Something which is interesting to mention is, that mostly the WFS that show single points within the dataset are not displayed correctly. Layers that project polygons are sometimes correct.

Comment: Please post text not images, for WMS and WFS.

Comment: https://rips-gdi.lubw.baden-wuerttemberg.de/arcgis/rest/services/wfs/Nationalpark_Zone/MapServer seems ro be configured incorrectly, apparently not visible at any scale according to this page  <<